# Convert generic Collection<Object> to Collection<Integer>

Tags: java, generics, casting

Welcome!
So, i'm currently working on Collection to array converter and i have problem.

```
    private static Collection<Object> resolveDesiredCollection(String desiredCollection){
        if (desiredCollection == null || desiredCollection.equals("")){
            desiredCollection = "al";
       }
       Collection<Object> collection;
       switch (desiredCollection) {
        case "al":
            collection = new ArrayList<>();
            break;
        case "all":
            collection = new LinkedList<>();
            break;
        case "hs":
            collection = new HashSet<>();
            break;
        case "ts":
            collection = new TreeSet<>();
            break;
        default:
            collection = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return collection;
    }

    public static Collection<Integer> intArrayToCollection(int [] array, String 
            desiredCollection){

        Collection<Integer> collection = (Collection<Integer>) 
            (resolveDesiredCollection(desiredCollection));

        Arrays.stream(array).forEach(i -> collection.add(new Integer(i)));

        return collection;
    }
```

How i can cast it? Showed way doesn't work, because compiler is screaming about "Inconvertible Types"  It's even possible? I want to avoid code repeat, so i dont want to create resolveDesiredCollection method for Integer,Double,String etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you make your `resolveDesiredCollection` method generic:

```
private static <T> Collection<T> resolveDesiredCollection(String desiredCollection)
{
    if (desiredCollection == null || desiredCollection.equals("")) {
        desiredCollection = "al";
    }
    Collection<T> collection;
    switch (desiredCollection) {
    case "al":
        collection = new ArrayList<>();
        break;
    case "all":
        collection = new LinkedList<>();
        break;
    case "hs":
        collection = new HashSet<>();
        break;
    case "ts":
        collection = new TreeSet<>();
        break;
    default:
        collection = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return collection;
}
```

You can simply call it with:

```
Collection<Integer> collection = resolveDesiredCollection(desiredCollection);
```

Your second method can also become generic:

```
public static <T> Collection<T> ArrayToCollection(T[] array, String desiredCollection)
{
    Collection<T> collection = resolveDesiredCollection(desiredCollection);

    Arrays.stream(array).forEach(i -> collection.add(i));

    return collection;
}
```

Of course, you can eliminate these methods and use existing JDK methods to achieve the same functionality.

For example, to convert an `Integer[]` to an `ArrayList<Integer>`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list =
    Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Can't believe i'm challenging with so trivial questions and can't solve it... Thanks mate :)

Comment: I know about existing methods, im doing converter to train usage of them ;)

Answer (score 1):

A `Collection<Object>` is not a `Collection<Integer>` and cannot be cast to one. But if you tell your `resolveDesiredCollection` what the element type should be by making it generic it can generate the correct type of collection and eliminate the need for the cast:

```
private static <T> Collection<T> resolveDesiredCollection(String desiredCollection){
    if (desiredCollection == null || desiredCollection.equals("")){
        desiredCollection = "al";
   }
   Collection<T> collection;
   switch (desiredCollection) {
    case "al":
        collection = new ArrayList<>();
        break;
    case "all":
        collection = new LinkedList<>();
        break;
    case "hs":
        collection = new HashSet<>();
        break;
    case "ts":
        collection = new TreeSet<>();
        break;
    default:
        collection = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return collection;
}
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need to do that at all.  The `elementType` argument is not used ... and not needed.

Comment: @StephenC you are right - in this case `T` can be inferred correctly without the parameter.